# Java - get extended class from object containing parent class

Tags: java, class, extends

I may have got the terminology wrong so I apologise, I am quite the Java rookie.

I am using the LibGDX framework to develop a mobile game and trying to make use of its Stage and Actor classes.

I have created my own class, StageExtension, which is an extension of the Stage class as I have added some of my own methods to it. So lets say I have;

```
StageExtension stageExt = new StageExtension():
Actor actor = new Actor();
stageExt.addActor(actor);
```

This works perfectly fine. The problem is when I want to get the Stage from the Actor to call one of my own StageExtension methods. The Actor hold reference to the Stage but only the "Stage", e.g. the Actor class has the getter;

```
public Stage getStage () {
    return stage;
}
```

So, clearly I don't understand Java very well. When I add the Actor to the Stage, it calls setStage() in the Actor, so the StageExtension is successfully being set as just a Stage in the Actor. When this happens, does Java just ignore my extended class?

How can I call my StageExtension instance from the Actor without copying and modifying these core classes?

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: do a cast on your getStage, StageExtension stageExt = (StageExtension)actor.getStage().

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was going to add I actually tried this already and got a null pointer exception, which I thought was the correct response, should this actually work then? I will try again, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: To avoid null pointer reference it as a `Stage` first, then check that the object is right. `Stage stage = actor.getStage();` followed by `if (stage instanceof StageExtension) { StageExtension stageExt = (StageExtension)stage; ... }`

Comment: doh! It completely works following dumitru's suggestion.  Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing there is an example of [Casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). What you've done is subclassed Stage with your new class StageExtension. So in your case all StageExtensions are Stages but not all Stages are StageExtensions. With that being the case Java can Cast a StageExtension to a Stage. So in your case if you do

```
StageExtension somesStage = new StageExtension ();
...
actor.setStage(somesStage)
```

Then java will try to Cast the StageExtension someStage to a Stage for you. In the Actor class it will be treated as a Stage, because that's what it thinks it is to all intents and purposes. This will work because a StageExtension is a subclass of Stage. To go the other way you should explicitly Cast the object

```
if(actor.getStage() instanceof StageExtension){
    StageExtension myStage = (StageExtension) actor.getStage()
}
```

Now Java will do it's best to cast this object to the subclass

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought casting the getStage() to a StageExtension would actually create a new instance and I would not have access to variables set in the existing StageExtension instance. It turns out I am wrong though and this works perfectly. You are right to check the Stage is in fact an instance of StageExtension first though, because it's perfectly possible it might not be in other instances. Would there be any memory or speed benefit doing it like this, or making my own version of the Actor class that contains StageExtension by default?

Comment: There would be no reason to subclass Actor to have an instance of StageExtension and would be harmful in some cases as you would then have to ensure the Actor's Stage and StageExtension remained in synch, for the other things that presumably use the Actor's Stage for things.

Comment: I was thinking if I will strictly only use the StageExtension in my app, but it works nicely like this anyway so thank you. Just a minor note, you have left out a closing bracket in your answer at StageExtension{.

Comment: Missing closing bracket? Never *cough*